# Migrate @EnableCircuitBreaker and @EnableEurekaClient to Spring Cloud 2022.0.1

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I upgraded Spring Cloud version to 2022.0.1 and I get error for imports not found:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.EnableCircuitBreaker;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
```

*Application class:*

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
```

Do you know how I can properly import them or upgrade them?

Comment: They didn't change packages or artifacts. Maybe corrupt downloads? What are you upgrading from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since Spring boot  2.5.12 @EnableCircuitBreaker is Deprecated, So you don't need to use it.
Also, this happened to @EnableEurekaClient and there is no need to annotate it
Just add these two dependencies to the project

> spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j
> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client